# Intersecting Shapes in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, shape

I've received an aep file and there's the following thing that drives me nuts:

There are obviously two overlapping shapes that where only the exclusion is filled:
[image]

Nothing special so far, but there are no masks included and also no Merge Paths:
[image]

So there are only two paths included (one for the circle and one for the rotated, overlapping rectangle), so which settings were used here to achieve the exclusion?
I personally would have used Merge Paths to achieve this result, but this is obviously not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely due to fill-rule being set to "`Even-Odd`". Try changing it to "`Non-Zero winding`" instead:

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to change anything.